# .htaccess | do you have to install the htacces in each directory for each error or just asingle one in the root directory?

Tags: file, .htaccess, redirect, error-handling

With this structure:

```
Root/ dir1/ dir2/ dir3/ dir4/dir5/ dirN...
```

Supposing I want to `Forbid` access to `dir4/`,

Where will I put the `.htaccess` file? inside that `dir4/` or in the `root/`?

or

Supposing someone links to `dir5/page3.php`, and the page does `not exist`, If I want them to be redirected to a `404.html` file... Will the `.htaccess` have to had been installed in `dir5/` or it is sufficient to have it in the `root` folder?

So, in general, where is(are) `.htaccess` file(s) supposed to be?

1) each folder? or

2) Just a single one in the main `root/` dir?

Please help thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are talking about are called..

**Server response codes**

> A server reponse code is a three digit number **sent by a server to a
>   user in response to a request for a web page or document**. They tell
>   the user whether the request can be completed, or if the server needs
>   more information, or if the server cannot complete the request.
>   Usually, **these codes are sent 'silently'** - so you never see them, as a
>   user - however, there are some common ones that you may wish to set up
>   error pages for, and they are listed below. Most people will only ever
>   need to set up error pages for server codes 400, 401, 403, 404 and
>   500, and you would be wise to always have an error document for 404
>   errors at the very least.

In order to set up an error page for any other error codes, you simply add lines to your `.htaccess` file. If you wanted to have error pages for the above five errors, your `.htaccess` file might look something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 400     /400.html 

ErrorDocument 401     /401.html 

ErrorDocument 403     /403.html 

ErrorDocument 404     /404.html 

ErrorDocument 500     /500.html
```

**Placing the `.htaccess` file in the `root/`** directory should do the tick.

For ref: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/error-documents-for-beginners/

or for PHP errors; http://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/

Comment: Cool... enjoy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Just a single .htaccess file in web root directory is enough.